# How to update incorrect dates across multiple tables in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with 1700+ tables that we received from a vendor.  The problem is that many of the dates in the tables are in an incorrect format.  What I want to do is come up with a script that will check all fields of type date, datetime, and timestamp and updating any fields that don't have a valid value.  Is such a thing possible?

Edit:Just for clarification, I'd like an script that would trawl a database and swap any dates less than 1900-01-01 with 1900-01-01.

Comment: Is there consistency across a table? So if you see 13-12-2013 do you know for sure that 01-02-2013 elsewhere in the same table is the 1st February? Otherwise you're going to be left guessing on a lot of things

Comment: I think that there is.

Comment: The culprits are dates like 0001-11-30.